# Is the following $f:S^3 \rightarrow S^2$ a submersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

I have $f:S^3 \rightarrow S^2$ given by
$$f(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_0^2+x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2, 2x_0x_3+2x_1x_2,2x_1x_3-2x_0x_2)$$

I define $\tilde{f}:S^3\subset \mathbb{R^4} \rightarrow S^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ so that I have $$d\tilde{f}_{(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)} = \begin{pmatrix} 2x_0 & 2x_1& -2x_2 &-2x_3\\ 2x_3& 2x_2& 2x_1&2x_3 \\ -2x_3 & 2x_3 & -2x_0 & 2x_1 \end{pmatrix}$$
I argued that since the differential has maximum rank, equal to 3 and equal to the dimension of the image, then the differential is surjective and therefore $f$ is a submersion.
Is it correct? Or, for example, do I have to argue something more regarding the differential ? Like $d\tilde{f}_x: T_xS^3 \subseteq T_x\mathbb{R^4} \rightarrow T_xS^2 \subseteq T_x\mathbb{R^3} $ ?

Comment: The last equality follows from the fact that the image of $\tilde f$, when restricted to $S^3$ lands in $S^2$. So you are done once you have done that.

Comment: @ThomasRot Thank you for your reply. Do you mean that $\tilde{f}|_{S^3}=f $?

Comment: Yeah basically that f is well defined

Comment: @Paul Frost I looked at the question, although is similar (or maybe equal) the answer is a bit odd for my knowledge. I am more familiar with the approach I used and with the comments and the answer here I should be fine.

Comment: You consider a map $\tilde f : \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^3$ and show that $d\tilde f_x$ has rank $3$ in all points. However, as  you say, you have to check additionally that $d\tilde f_x(T_x S^3) = T_{f(x)}S^2$ for all $x \in S^3$. See point 1. of the linked answer.

Answer (score 2):

You reasoning is perfectly fine. Just as a remark: you need to show it has maximal rank **for every point $x=(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3) \in S^3$**, and indeed this is the case, just use Gauss reduction algorithm to see it has maximal rank.

Recall indeed the definition of submersion : *a submersion is a differentiable map between differentiable manifolds whose differential is everywhere surjective*. It is exactly what you proved.

Different would be to ask if it is a [Riemannian submersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_submersion), but this is a different notion.